# Bootstrap datetimepicker strange positioning on a different div altogether

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker with formatting to enable only editing time in my code, I do it like this:

```
function setTimepicker(object){
    object.datetimepicker({
                format: 'HH:mm'
            });
}
```

I call this function in document.ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimepicker(starttimefield);
   setTimepicker(endtimefield);
});
```

The html I am using is like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form id="myform">
         <p> <b>Create a New Event:</b></p>                                      
         <br>
         <p>Description for main page: <br>
            <textarea id="summary" name="summary" maxlength="100"></textarea>
         </p>
         <p> Full description: <br>
            <textarea id="description" name="description" maxlength="500"></textarea>
         </p>
         <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="titles">
                 <p> Event date:  
                 </p>
                 <p> Start time:                                         
                 </p>                                        
                 <p> End time:    
                 </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="values">
                     <input type="text" id="eventdate" readonly/><br>
                     <div id="starttimepicker">
                         <input type="text" id="starttime" onkeydown="return false"/><br>
                     </div>
                     <div id="endttimepicker">
                         <input type="text" id="endtime" onkeydown="return false"/>                                            
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <p> Location: <input type="text" id="location"/> </p>

            <p><input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<?php echo Auth::id();?>"/></p>
            <p><input id="saveevent" type="button" value="Save Event" />
                                        </p>
     </form>
</div>
```

Except for the standard css files (jquery-ui.css, bootstrap-datetimepicker.css) I added 1 extra css file that contains:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.titles {
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
}
.values {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Now for the issue at hand, the fields endtime and starttime should have a timepicker when clicked (this works) but look at where it renders the timepicker in this image:

[image]

Can anyone help me to get that timepicker element next to (or above or close by, anything) the field that it belongs to

Comment: Use alloy UI component it is also using Jquery for base javascript framework

Comment: Sorry I'm really new at all of this stuff (back end developer) could you explain what to get and how to use it in an answer?

Comment: Jeremy C Just explore Alloy UI You Will get all the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an `.input-group` wrapper which has a position value of "relative". Since the datepicker is absolutely positioned it's container needs to be relatively positioned for the datepicker to be positioned correctly.

So I believe something like this would work:

```
.values {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Better yet, let's set position relative on the divs that actually hold our inputs like so:

```
#starttimepicker {
  position: relative;
}

#endtimepicker {
  position: relative;
}
```

If you want my opinion though that is not very DRY. If you have control over the html you might try to add a class of "values__datepicker" (or whatever class) to #starttimepicker and #endtimepicker and set just one CSS rule like so:

```
.values__datepicker {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: this made it slightly better (on the correct position now) but now it's not rendering the picker element look here http://oi61.tinypic.com/20giq36.jpg

Comment: Yeah, you have `overflow` set to "hidden". I wasn't sure why you were doing that but it will hide anything absolutely positioned. If you don't need it for anything in specific you should remove it. If you need it for something let me know what that something is and we can try a better solution.

Comment: To be completely honest I have it because I used some copy paste code I got from somewhere when I was trying to line up 2 divs next to eachother and I know absolutely nothing about css or styling in general :D but thanks, that did the trick

Comment: @leubauza I just noticed that the timepicker for starttime is actually rendering on the right place but the one for endtime is being rendered above the field for the date instead of endtime do you know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Alright, so what we did was set `position: relative` on the .values container so everything will be positioned related to that. Which I now see is not really ideal. So, see my post for updated answer.

Comment: you're a lifesaver man, I don't know anything about positioning in css but you make it really easy for me to understand, it's working as required now, thanks a heap