# Bootstrap-datepicker positioned on the left top corner of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using `bootstrap-datepicker` from https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker (with `twitter-bootstrap 3`). When clicking on the date `input`, datepicker popup opens in the **top left corner** of the page, not near the `input` element.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('#BirthDate,#passDate,#docDate').datepicker({
          format: "mm.dd.yyyy",
          startDate: "-100y",
          language: "ru",
          orientation: "auto",
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true,
          toggleActive: true,
          defaultViewDate: { year: 2016, month: 1, day: 1 }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Example: https://abonent.pskovregiongaz.ru/Gro/AskForVDGO

Tested in: IE, FireFox.

[image]

Tested with latest stable and v1.7.0-dev. I have no clue, what else to do.

**UPDATE:** HTML source.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>    
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="/Gro/AskForVDGO" id="form0" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BirthDate">Дата рождения</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="01.01.0001" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Отправить" title="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('#BirthDate').datepicker({
          format: "mm.dd.yyyy",
          startDate: "-100y",
          language: "ru",
          orientation: "auto",
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true,
          toggleActive: true,
          defaultViewDate: { year: 2016, month: 1, day: 1 }
      });
  });
</script>
</body></html>
```

**UPDATE 2**: @TechBreak answer lead to persistent datapicker (opened on load, didn't close) element on page. Datapicker persists under input element, and shown permanently. More date `input` elements - more datepickers shown at moment.
[image]

Comment: post your html markups please

Comment: @TechBreak done, I have posted it

Comment: You can try these, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966645/bootstrap-datepicker-appearing-at-incorrect-location-in-a-modal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755513/bootstrap-datetimepicker-strange-positioning-on-a-different-div-altogether

Comment: @Vaibhav , tried solutions from this topics. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found help at GitHub (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/2079):

It happens because you use: `body{ margin: 0 auto; }`. Current version calculate this margin value wrong. ugly fix for it - in 'bootstrap-datepicker.js' - >place:

`function(): var left = offset.left - appendOffset.left,`

replace it on: `var left = offset.left,`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Change your orientation from auto to left and apply datepicker on your div instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('#datepickerEl').datepicker({
          format: "mm.dd.yyyy",
          startDate: "-100y",
          language: "ru",
          orientation: "left",
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true,
          toggleActive: true,
          defaultViewDate: { year: 2016, month: 1, day: 1 }
      });
  });
</script>
```

And instead of,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="BirthDate">Дата рождения</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="01.01.0001" />
</div>
```

Do this,

```
<div class="form-group" id="datepickerEl">
    <label for="BirthDate">Дата рождения</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="01.01.0001" />
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work :( Now, datapicker persists under `input` element, and shown permanently. More date input elements - more datepickers shown at moment. See image in UPDATE 2.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the:

```
<div class="form-group">
```

so it becomes:

```
<div class="form-group" id="birthDateContainer">
```

and then add container: `#birthDateContainer` to the datepicker function so it becomes:

```
$(function() {
    $('#BirthDate').datepicker({
        format: "mm.dd.yyyy",
        startDate: "-100y",
        language: "ru",
        orientation: "auto",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        toggleActive: true,
        defaultViewDate: {
            year: 2016,
            month: 1,
            day: 1
        },
        container: '#birthDateContainer'
    });
});
```

that should do it.